# Detect button click from WebView in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, create-react-app

Can anyone please help me on how to detect Webview button click event in React Native? As shown in the code below, I have a Button in my WebView (index.html) for which i want to detect click event from React Native and execute the method onClick. I have tried multiple ways, but couldn't succeed. Thanks so much in Advance.

my MyApp.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, WebView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
onClick = () => {
  console.log('Button Clicked');
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
                style={styles.webView}
                source={require('./index.html')}/>
        </View>
    );
}
};

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
webView: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    height: 350,
}
});
```

my index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <Button>Click Here</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `window.postMessage()` to your page file and `onMessage={this.onMessage}` to your React Native WebView component.

Example:

```
// index.html (Web)
...
<script>
  window.postMessage("Sending data from WebView");
</script>
...


// MyWebView.js (React Native)
<WebView>
...
<WebView
   ref="webview"
    onMessage={this.onMessage}
/>
  
onMessage(data) {
  //Prints out data that was passed.
  console.log(data);
}
```

Edit:
Working example:

App.js

```
onMessage(m) {
 alert(m.nativeEvent.data);
}
render() {
  return(
    <WebView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      source={{uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8877'}} //my localhost
      onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)} 
    />
  );
}
```

index.html

```
<button>Send post message from web</button>

<script>
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  console.log("Send post message");
  window.postMessage("Hello React", "*");
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks much for responding on this, I have tried this as well, but no luck. Is it possible for you a working example. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227576/9673374 please check this thread for the compatibility with latest version

Answer (score 2):

`window.postMessage` doesn't work for me for current last version. And found many other solutions that maybe worked for someone in some version but not for me.

Check how I solve it with `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-webview": "^11.0.2",
```

**Note: that I am using html string instead of url**

```js
<WebView
    bounces={false}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html }}
    onLoadEnd={this.onLoadEnd}
    onError={this.onError}
    mixedContentMode={'never'} // security
    startInLoadingState={true} // when starting this component
    onMessage={onMessage}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
/>
```

```js
onMessage = (message: string) => {
    console.log('action result coming from the webview: ', message);
};
```

And in the `html` string I added the script below and set the `onclick` for a given html `button` or `a` tag:

```html
...
<div>
    <button onclick="clickYourButton([PASS SOME STRING DATA HERE])">Click</button>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickYourButton(data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data)
        }, 0) // *** here ***
    }
</script>
```

- Data to be passed to the `postMessage` func should be `string`