# Can we use react-navigation's navigation prop inside WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-navigation

I want to navigate to another screen when i click on a button (html).
Can we use navigation prop inside webview?

I tried but it is only displaying true instead of navigating.

Comment: This should solve your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936566/detect-button-click-from-webview-in-react-native?rq=1