# detect browser back button click react native

Tags: react-native, browser, react-native-navigation, react-native-web

I need some help here.

I want to do some action when a user clicks the browser back/forward button. But I am getting how to detect the browser button clicks or not. I am using react-native. Can anyone help me out? like which package I should use or with pseudo code? Thank You.

Comment: see that same issue .[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936566/detect-button-click-from-webview-in-react-native) that's maybe helpful:)

Comment: @MeisamSaba thanks for the replay, I don't want any extra button. I just want to detect the browser back/forward button(located in the left corner of the browser) click.

Comment: u can set `window.postMessage("Hello React", "*");` on back/forward button `onclick` function . I guess that possible.

Comment: You provided very little detail, but I assume you may be looking for something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122592/how-do-i-go-back-in-webview-i-am-using-the-react-navigation-package-in-react-na/57441046#57441046

Comment: @Rich Are you using the Linking module from RN or wanted to detect a button from Webview?

Comment: You should give more details because the browser context with RN is kind a confusing.

Comment: did you looked at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser