# Set state depending on whether document.getelementbyid exists

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, getelementbyid, setstate

So I currently am using InjectJavascript to change the values of html elements of my webview. I am able to assign those values to the values that I have in my state. How would I go about setting a few state variables equal to document.getElementById('data').value? It seems like ReactNative and the javascript code are not compatible with each other.

I have tried if(document.getElementById('data').value.length > 0) { ${this.setState({data: document.getElementById('data').value})}}, but it does not work

```
const jsCode= `
  document.getElementById('username').value='${this.state.userName}';  
  document.getElementById('password').value='${this.state.userPassword}';
  document.getElementById('logIn').click();
`

<WebView
   style={styles.webView}
   source={{uri: 'http://example.com'}}
   javaScriptEnabled
   injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
   renderLoading={()=>{
     return(
       <ActivityIndicator style = {
          { position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0,
            top: 0, bottom: 0, alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }
       }/>
     )}
   }>
 </WebView>
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want to `setState` based on some value change in the view? If so, would this not be tied to a specific input event? And then we could assign some handler function to actually perform the `setState`?

Comment: yes, so essentially i am creating a react native mobile app for logging into a website. I am using injectedjavascript to put the textinput data into the fields into the webview. I am trying to essentially switch to an errorview on my app, when an html element "invalid" appears on the webview.

Comment: In the jscode, i tried to see if the document contains an element by classname "invalid", then i should set state, this.setstate({switchtoerrorview: true})

Comment: OK, what would trigger the "invalid" element? Could you hook into some event logic (e.g. some text input handler) that could check for when the error condition is going to happen? Then in that way you could trigger a `setState` call from that same handler

Comment: The invalid element is triggered when the email and password are incorrect. It seems like I only have access to "document.getelementbyid" inside of the injected javascript code. But I am not able to use both react components and javascript together. Like I am not able to print out a document.getelementbyid value using console.log, unless I use template literals, like ${console.log}, but then I do not have access to document.getelementbyid inside of the literal.

Answer (score 0):

To pass some data from `WebView` component to react-native side you can use [`onMessage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage) prop.

**Note:** There is [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594) related to `postMessage`. The example injected code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620104/2315280) to solve this issue.

> **onMessage**
>
> A function that is invoked when the `WebView` calls
>   `window.postMessage`. Setting this property will inject a
>   `postMessage` global into your `WebView`, but will still call
>   pre-existing values of `postMessage`.
>
> `window.postMessage` accepts one argument, data, which will be
>   available on the event object, `event.nativeEvent.data`. **data must
>   be a string**.

**Example**

```
const jsCode = `function waitForBridge() {
   //the react native postMessage has only 1 parameter
   //while the default one has 2, so check the signature
   //of the function
   if (window.postMessage.length !== 1){
     setTimeout(waitForBridge, 200);
   }
   else {
     window.postMessage('abc'); // postMessage expects a string
   }
}

window.onload = waitForBridge;`

//...

<WebView
   style={styles.webView}
   source={{uri: 'http://example.com'}}
   javaScriptEnabled
   injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
   onMessage={(event) => console.log('Posted Message: ', event.nativeEvent.data)}
   renderLoading={()=>{
     return(
       <ActivityIndicator style = {
          { position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0,
            top: 0, bottom: 0, alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }
       }/>
     )}
   }>
 </WebView>
```

Comment: So essentially, when I finish all of my events, such as filling in the username/password/clicking, i can wait for the webview to send a message, and when I receive a message, i can set state accordingly. Do I have the gist of it?

Comment: Yes. you got the idea. You can wait for them to fill all or you can post a message in every change. how you implement is up to you. just remember you need to pass a string so if you want to pass some data like an object you can use `window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({some:'object}))` and then parse the json object on react side.