# ReactNativeWebView is Not Recognised

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I’m using `react-native-webview` and attempting to post a message from JavaScript to RN.

I’m using the `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage()` method but cannot get beyond some issue with `ReactNativeWebView` not being recognised, with the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined
```

I’m using the following:

- "react": "16.8.3",
- "react-native": "0.59.8",
- "react-native-webview": "^5.12.0",

This looks so straight forward so I don’t know where I’m going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare and use the reference value.

```js
 onLoadEnd() {
   this.webview.postMessage("yourmessage");
  }

 <WebView
          ref={webview => (this.webview = webview)}
          onLoadEnd={() => this.onLoadEnd()}
          ...
        />
```

Your webview_uri should have a message-receiver just like React-native's.

**webpage example**

```
document.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    console.log("Received post message", event);

    logMessage(event.data);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that I had tried this but, with all the combintion of efforts, I'm not 100%. I shall give it a go and follow what you have provided. Many thanks.

Comment: I hope you will pay a lot of attention to Reat-native. I need a developer like you. If my answer was helpful, could you choose an answer?

Comment: Still no luck for me, hong develop. I no longer get any errors but the post message is never received by the WebView. I'm using react-native-webview 5.12.0 and so am referring to the implementation described by @osrpt, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619813/react-native-webview-onmessage-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: Is there a listener in your uri that listens to messages?

Comment: Yes: `onMessage={() => this.onMessage()}`

Comment: Or tested directly: `onMessage={() => console.log("onMessage")}`

Comment: I mean, is there a place to receive messages from a web page?

Comment: Ouch! How crazy of me. This inow seems so glaringly obvious. I've been adding the message handler to RN, not the contents of the WebView - useful for messages from the WebView but hopeless in my scenario. Very optimistic this will now work - can't wait to give it a go! Thank you very much for your persistence, hong develop.

Comment: Yeah, I hope you to try and choose my answer if this works.

Comment: Thanks hong develop. That works well. I'm unfortunately not able to get a message back from the WebView. I've prepared the detail, and all code used, but don't know how to post on this forum. I can't alter my original question, as the new question is different. I can't express myself in these comments. And I can't answer my own question because Stack Overflow won't allow a new question. I shall try to ask the updated question on another forum which provides that ability to discuss a query further, and then link to it in these comments. Thank you very much for getting me this far!

Comment: Hi hong develop, I've now added my new issue to this post, in case you were interested. Thank you for everything, regardless! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737292/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-the-webview-to-react-native

Comment: I see. So if the answer to this question helped you, can you choose my answer?