# How can I send a message from the WebView to React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I’ve successfully managed to send a message from React Native (RN) to a WebView.

What I’m struggling with, is getting the message back from the WebView to RN. There’s no errors showing - it’s just that the message never gets through.

Here is the code which I’m using:

**React Native Code**

```
<WebView
  ref={webview => (this.webview = webview)}
  source={{ uri: "http://www.my-web-site"}}
  onLoadEnd={() => this.onLoadEnd()}
  onMessage={this.onMessage}
  cacheEnabled={false}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>

onLoadEnd() {
  this.webview.postMessage("RN message");
}

onMessage(message) {
  console.log("I can’t see this message!");
}
```

**WebView Code**

```
document.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  setTimeout(function(){document.postMessage("WebView message")}, 3000);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 8):

Please make sure that the data for each receiver is in and use the data that You need.

And always check the prescribed documents to see how to use parameters and grammar before using them.

**RN**

```js
onLoadEnd() {

  this.webview.postMessage("sendmessage");
}

onMessage(event) {
  alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
}
```

**WebView Code**

```js
    document.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        window.postMessage(event.data);
    });
```

**React-native version 5.0 or later**

```js
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.data);
```

Comment: This still isn't working for me, unfortunately. The odd thing is, I check other forums and documentation online and what you have there looks perfect! But it just doesn't work for me. Nothing is ever received in the WebView's `onMessage` handler. Do note that I'm using `react-native-webview`, not just the `react-native` WebView. I don't know if that would make any difference.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not looking anymore but if someone gets lost here, from RN 5.0 you should use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.data);` instead of `window.postMessage(event.data); ` it has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55213143/4739273 and explained here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v5.0.0

Comment: I wasted hours try to make this work and found that `window.ReactNativeWebView && window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.data)` worked for me. Just in case if anyone has the same issue as me :)

Answer (score 3):

Oh, at last, I finally came across the answer. It was a line of code which I had originally been trying to use to send a message from RN to the WebView. Turns out, it was the code required for sending from the WebView to RN:

**WebView Code**

```
document.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.data);
}, false);
```

**RN Code**

```
<WebView onMessage={event => console.log(event.nativeEvent.data)} />
```

Answer (score 3):

This works.

**React Native**

```js
<WebView source={{ ... }}
         containerStyle={{ ... }}
         onMessage={ e => { console.log(e.nativeEvent.data) } }
/>
```

**WebView**

```js
if(window.ReactNativeWebView) {
   // send data object to React Native (only string)
   window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(dataObject))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send complete object from webview to react-native android app then you need to stringify your object first

// Reactjs webapp

```js
  onClickSendObject = (item) => {
    if(window.ReactNativeWebView) {     
       window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(item))
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In react-native app use onMessage (for functional component)

```js
<WebView
  ref={webview => (this.webview = webview)}
  source={{ uri: "give source url i.e your webapp link"}}
  onMessage={m => onMessage(m.nativeEvent.data)} // functional component and for class component use (this.onMessage) 
  cacheEnabled={false}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
/>

// onMessage function

const onMessage = (m) => {
    const messageData = JSON.parse(m);
    console.log(messageData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(window["ReactNativeWebView"] || window).postMessage('hello motiur dear','*');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer