# Integrate Python OpenCV with React Native/Android/iOS

Tags: java, python, reactjs, react-native, opencv

I have an app built on React Native whose core functionality is to capture some images, analyse and process the images and return some results. As of now the image analysis was done in the server side using python and opencv. Only the results and the resultant images were returned. Now as per the requirement by the clients, due to privacy concerns, they want the image processing to be done on the mobile app itself. (As the images are medical related and they don't want the images to be sent to the server)

So, my question is, if there is a way I can use my existing python with opencv code and integrate it directly into react-native/android/ios?

Right now what I am doing is using the library [react-native-opencv3](https://github.com/adamgf/react-native-opencv3) , [numjs](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/numjs), etc to re-write the algorithm in react-native as I feel comfortable using javascript (I have no experience in swift). However not all opencv, numpy functions are supported by these libraries and it is consuming all the time to re-write the code.

I found about using [jython](https://www.jython.org/), [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) and [swift-python-interoperability](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/python_interoperability)
Can I use these to directly integrate python opencv code into my current application? If yes, it would be great if someone can help me with some small example or guidelines as I cannot find anything.

Other method that I considered was:

Re-write the algorithm using native code and opencv-android and opencv-ios sdks and create the react-native bridge to call the algorithm. (I am guessing it will take a lot of time as I have to write in 2 different languages. Time that I don't have)

Comment: I'm researching the same thing. License plate recognition system is my project. It would be nice to solve the work on the client side for working offline.

The method that comes to my mind for now; delete images after processing on the server. My research continues.

Comment: @SonerPALANCI i am in the midst of using opencv.js with webview. The html for the webview along with the js can be kept locally in the assets folder. All you need to do is inject the image into the webview, then do the image proc using opencv js, then get the image as data back to react native. However its still not completed. I will share the soln once its done.

Comment: @edeesan I found this post since I am looking to port some OpenCV code to mobile, and was considering using React Native. It has been some time since your comment here, and unfortunately there's not much new on official bindings. But the method in your comment (webview <-> opencv.js) is interesting. I'm wondering -- did it work?

Comment: @Tee it indeed worked. I just didnt get the time to update the answer here. But the concept is the same. I injected the image in the webiew and the did the image processing in webview, while hiding the webview and showing a progress bar. Then returned the results from webview to React Native.

Comment: Refer to this link for communication between webview and RN: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737292/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-the-webview-to-react-native

Comment: One more thing, I could only make it work for Android. Didnt get enough funding for iOS. But I assume it should work with some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @edeesan ! Very cool to hear that it worked.