# How to Integrate Python OpenCV with React Native

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, opencv

`Link to a related question`
[Link to Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727047/integrate-python-opencv-with-react-native-android-ios)

Read the question from the link above , OP's problem is something different but not entirely different, he asks how to move the openCV-python code he has from the server to the front end but it does not matter to me , any approach will do.

`Aim:`
I want to write a text detector in openCV using the python programming language and connect to my React-native app without writing any native (Swift/Java) Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you split this project into 2 parts, one with the opencv python model and another with only the react native app.

1. Make the python openCV model into a simple flask API and then deploy it online. I would recommend you to deploy it on heroku as it is easy.

> [Here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/01/build-api-machine-learning-model-using-flask.html) you can find how to make a very simple Flask API.
>
> [Here](https://stackabuse.com/deploying-a-flask-application-to-heroku/) you can find how to deploy your Flask application.

2. Make the react native app and use the API which you made in step 1 to POST your information (in this case an image of the text) to the model via the API and then retrieve the results back in the form of text data (with `fetch()` fuction). Then you can process this data to suit your application requirements.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help.