# I am calling an api in webview in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I am calling an API in WebView in react native, I wanted to store the returned response in react state, can anyone have any idea like how to do it?

I am using react native class component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a message from the WebView to React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737292/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-the-webview-to-react-native)