# Event from event.nativeEvent.data logs as setImmediate$0.4162155499933975$1

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to pass token and other user details from React Web application to React Native application with Webview (react-native).

When I do

```
window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(reactNativeObj), '*');
```

and log the event in React native application with

```
console.log( "On Message", event.nativeEvent.data );
```

It is printing the log as

```
On Message: setImmediate$0.4162155499933975$1
```

It should print my object instead.

I have tried almost everything and re-read the document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage but couldn't make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227576/5793132

Comment: @TrueTiem I am getting the event from web-view, but it is getting returned as `setImmediate$0.41236..`.

Comment: Try to change `window.postMessage...` with `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(...`. Also try to JSON.parse your object and log it alone to see what's printed

Comment: Which versions of React Native and [react-native-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `RN >= 0.60` then you're using [`react-native-webview >= 8.0.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview), which you'll have to use [`window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native).

If you have access and can edit the website code, then you should add a `postMessage` call like this:

```js
if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(reactNativeObj));
}
```

If you don't have access to the website code or if you don't want to alter its' contents, then you can inject some code that modifies `window.postMessage` to use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` along with the default method:

```
const WebView_Injection_postMessage = `
(function() {
  window.default_postMessage = window.postMessage;
  window.postMessage = function(data, domain) {
    window.default_postMessage(data, domain);
    if (window.ReactNativeWebView) {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
    }
  }
})();
`;

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState('');

  function onWebViewMessage(event) {
    console.log('onWebViewMessage', event.nativeEvent.data);

    setResult(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data), null, 2));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.webViewContainer}>
          <WebView
            source={{ uri: 'https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/60052061/react' }}
            style={styles.webWiew}
            injectedJavaScript={WebView_Injection_postMessage}
            onMessage={onWebViewMessage}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.resultView}>
          <Text style={styles.resultText}>{result}</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
`;
```

The web app at https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/60052061/react is a React 16 development app with the following code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  postMessage = () => {
    console.log('Posting message...');

    const reactNativeObj = {
      location: window.location.href,
      title: document.title,
      dt: (new Date).toISOString()
    }

    window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(reactNativeObj), '*');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.postMessage} id="post-message">Post Message</button>
    )
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('main'));

</script>
```

Last but not least, `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` accepts only one parameter with the data to be send and it has to be a string.

> [window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage only accepts one argument which must be a string.](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-windowreactnativewebviewpostmessage-method-and-onmessage-prop)

Here is a screen capture with the working app:

[image: React 16 postMessage to React Native WebView]